# How to select a specific category value in this Xpath expression

Tags: xpath

I have a feed [here](https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/devportal-reference-docs/fire-app-builder/feeds/feed1.xml). I'm trying to create an XPath expression that returns items that have a category equal to Bananas. Due to the limitations in my XML parser, I can't use namespaces directly to select items.

The expression `/rss/channel/item//*[name()='itunes:category']` returns this:

```
Element='<itunes:category 
xmlns:itunes="http://www.itunes.com/dtds/podcast-1.0.dtd" 
text="Apples"/>'
Element='<itunes:category 
xmlns:itunes="http://www.itunes.com/dtds/podcast-1.0.dtd" 
text="Bananas"/>'
...
```

And `/rss/channel/item//*[name()='itunes:category']/@text` returns this:

```
Attribute='text=Apples'
Attribute='text=Bananas'
...
```

But I can't figure out how to limit the response to just a single category (e.g., Bananas)?

I want some kind of expression like this:

`/rss/channel/item//*[name()='itunes:category' and contains(., 'Bananas')]`

But this doesn't work. It's not syntactically valid. What would be the right XPath expression syntax to just return Bananas?

Comment: Did you try `/rss/channel/item//*[name()='itunes:category' and @text='Bananas']`?

Answer (score 1):

Do you just mean to filter by attributes of item child, but still return item node?

```
/rss/channel/item/*[name()='itunes:category' and contains(@text,'Apples')]/parent::item
```

or simplier

```
/rss/channel/item[*[name()='itunes:category' and @text='Apples']]
```

I used Apples in example because using your example xml file there is 0 results for Bananas.